# Navigation menus not working as expected in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter v3.1.3.  Based on the 'Static Page' tutorial, I am trying to create a static website containing 5 pages such as Home, About, Services, Portfolio, and Contact.

I have a Pages.php controller inside `'application/controllers'` directory.

My Pages.php controller looks like

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pages extends CI_Controller {
    //Controller logic
    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
        if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
            //Whoops!, we don't have a page for that
            show_404(); //In-built CI function to show 404 error pages
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); //Capitalize the first letter
        $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page,$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer',$data);
    }
}
```

I have also created the 5 static pages inside `'application/views/pages'` like home.php, about.php, services.php, portfolio.php, contact.php

Common codes of header & footer exists at `'application/views/templates'` like footer.php & header.php.
My navigation menu inside header.php looks like

```
<li><a class="curr_menu" href="<?php echo base_url('pages/view/home');?>">Home</a>
</li>
<li><a class="page-scroll" href="<?php echo base_url('pages/view/about');?>">About Us</a>
</li>
<li><a class="page-scroll" href="<?php echo base_url('pages/view/services');?>">Services</a>
</li>
<li><a class="page-scroll" href="<?php echo base_url('pages/view/portfolio');?>">Portfolio</a>
</li>
<li><a class="page-scroll" href="<?php echo base_url('pages/view/contact');?>">Contact Us</a>
</li>
```

My routes.php(application/config/routes.php) looks like

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

The homepage is shown initial load, however when I click on any menu items, it returns '**404 Page Not Found**' error.

Can someone please explain - with clear code - show to make my menu work.
.htaccess at the root contains

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: did you manage `.htacess` file?

Comment: yes i have a htaccess file.I have edited my question to include my htaccess file

Comment: `href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/pages/view/home');?>"` it works or not.try once

Comment: When index.php is added then it works, but i don't want to show index.php in my URLs

Comment: try below edited answer.Working here perfectly.

Comment: once try remove this `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';` from routes.

Comment: Removed $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1'; but still its the same page not found error

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to manually navigate to the wanted pages by writing the URL by hand in the address bar to make sure the error comes from the link building.

If so, then try using

```
<?php echo site_url('pages/view/home');?>
```

Comment: changing base_url() with site_url() produces the same page not found error

Answer (score 0):

In order to  use `base_url()` you have to load url helper first in your controller.Like this

```
 public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');

       }
```

Or you can load it in `application/config/autolaod.php`.Like this...

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

And don't forget to set bae_url at `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'your_url';
```

Also

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

In your root folder. `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Yes @Hek, its there like $autoload['helper'] = array('url');

Comment: try to load from controller.

Comment: Yes @Hek a config code is there just like you have mentioned above

Comment: @Hekmat You missed parent::__construct()  where the url helper is loaded in controller

Comment: Still the problem persists.In config.php its $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/asci/'; where 'asci' is my project folder.

Comment: Same as before - 404 Page Not Found. The link <a class="page-scroll" href="<?=base_url()?>index.php/pages/view/about">About Us</a> Works however <a class="page-scroll" href="<?php echo base_url('pages/view/contact');?>">Contact Us</a> does not work

Answer (score 0):

Probably your url is coming out wrong. Your default controller is
"Pages/view " ??
If so, then the navigation menus should be like this :

```
<li><a class="curr_menu" href="<?=base_url()?>home">Home</a>
</li>
<li><a class="curr_menu" href="<?=base_url()?>about">About Us</a>
</li>
<li><a class="curr_menu" href="<?=base_url()?>services">Services</a>
</li>
<li><a class="curr_menu" href="<?=base_url()?>portfolio">Portfolio</a>
</li>
<li><a class="curr_menu" href="<?=base_url()?>contact">Contact Us</a>
</li>
```

And in the config.php file,

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://yoururl/'; //should be followed by forward slash (/)
    $config['index_page'] = '';
```